# Использование ботом премиум эмодзи

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Суть проста : Необходимо реализовать возможность использования ботом в своих сообщениях премиум эмодзи телеграмм. В интернете полезной информации не нашёл, так что обращаюсь к вам

Сколько раз не пробовал, любыми способами которые находил, бот заменял премиум эмодзи на дефолт.

Бот написан с использованием aiogram